# Fatal Error relativo ao page.php do tema

Tags: php, wordpress

Meu site apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sanzo_get_page_options() in /home/julisaupiscinasc/public_html/wp-content/themes/sanzo/page.php on line 3

O código referido na mensagem é o seguinte:

```
<?php
global $sanzo_theme_options;
$page_options = sanzo_get_page_options();
get_header( $sanzo_theme_options['ts_header_layout'] );

$extra_class = "";
```

Já reinstalei os componentes do tema e continua o erro. Alguém passou por algo parecido e pode me ajudar?

Comment: É wordpress? o erro diz que a função não existe.

Comment: Sim é wordpress. Já passou por algo parecido ou tem ideia do que pode ter causado?

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo sua pergunta, o erro é que não existe a função: `sanzo_get_page_options()` que está sendo chamada no arquivo: `/home/julisaupiscinasc/public_html/wp-content/themes/sanzo/page.php` na linha `3`

Você terá que ver o que essa função faz, e criá-la ou achar a mesma na internet, de acordo com seu template.